# How to create two pie charts using Chart.js API?

Tags: javascript, html, pie-chart, chart.js

This is my HTML page:

```
    <div>
        <canvas id="chart-area1" width="300" height="300"/>
    </div>
<script src="Chart.js"></script>
<script>

    var pieData1 = [
            {
                value: 300,
                color:"#F7464A",
                highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                label: "Red"
            },
            {
                value: 50,
                color: "#46BFBD",
                highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                label: "Green"
            },
            {
                value: 100,
                color: "#FDB45C",
                highlight: "#FFC870",
                label: "Yellow"
            },
            {
                value: 40,
                color: "#949FB1",
                highlight: "#A8B3C5",
                label: "Grey"
            },
            {
                value: 120,
                color: "#4D5360",
                highlight: "#616774",
                label: "Dark Grey"
            }

        ];

        window.onload = function(){
            var ctx1 = document.getElementById("chart-area1").getContext("2d");
            var myPie1 = new Chart(ctx1).Pie(pieData1);

        };



</script>

<div>
        <canvas id="chart-area2" width="300" height="300"/>
    </div>
<script src="Chart1.js"></script>
<script>

    var pieData2 = [
            {
                value: 300,
                color:"#F7464A",
                highlight: "#FF5A5E",
                label: "Red"
            },
            {
                value: 50,
                color: "#46BFBD",
                highlight: "#5AD3D1",
                label: "Green"
            },
            {
                value: 100,
                color: "#FDB45C",
                highlight: "#FFC870",
                label: "Yellow"
            },
            {
                value: 40,
                color: "#949FB1",
                highlight: "#A8B3C5",
                label: "Grey"
            },
            {
                value: 120,
                color: "#4D5360",
                highlight: "#616774",
                label: "Dark Grey"
            }

        ];

        window.onload = function(){
            var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart-area2").getContext("2d");
            var myPie2 = new Chart(ctx2).Pie(pieData2);
        };



</script>
```

'Chart.js' and 'Chart1.js' contains same content. I used 'Chart.js' only once but it didn't work. So I tried with two.

The above HTML page is displaying only one pie chart. The other pie chart is not displayed but occupying the space in the page.

What changes should be made so that two pie charts can be displayed?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well never having used this library before, I think that the problem lies in the fact that you have 2 `window.onload` functions. To my knowledge, you can only have one. Try moving the code from your second one into your first, and delete the second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set `window.onload` to a value twice, causing it to be overwritten with the latest value:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx1 = document.getElementById("chart-area1").getContext("2d");
    var myPie1 = new Chart(ctx1).Pie(pieData1);
};
// ...
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart-area2").getContext("2d");
    var myPie2 = new Chart(ctx2).Pie(pieData2);
};
```

Why not combine the two functions?

Like:

```
var func1 = function() { /* set up chart 1 */ },
    func2 = function() { /* set up chart 2 */ };

window.onload = function() {
    func1();
    func2();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you reassign window.onload so it only loads the second one. Try doing this instead:

```
window.onload = function(){
        var ctx1 = document.getElementById("chart-area1").getContext("2d");
        var myPie1 = new Chart(ctx1).Pie(pieData1);
        var ctx2 = document.getElementById("chart-area2").getContext("2d");
        var myPie2 = new Chart(ctx2).Pie(pieData2);
};
```

Comment: window.load can have multiple event handlers. You're not reassigning it, you're stacking them up...

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the code for the pichat which worked for me. 
<link href="../JSfiles/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../ChartsJs/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="../ChartsJs/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../ChartsJs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
     <script src="http://www.chartjs.org/assets/Chart.min.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
             $(document).ready(function () {
             debugger;
             $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'json',
                 contentType: 'application/json',
                 url: 'PubPerformancePichat.aspx/GetDataonload',
                 data: {},
                 success: function (response) {
                     drawchart(response.d); // calling method
                 },

                 error: function () {
                     //alert("Error:Something went wrong.Contact the Adminstrator");
                     //alert(response);
                 }
             })
         });
         function drawchart(dataValues) {
             var arr = [];
             var arrcolor = '#231F20, #FFC200, #F44937, #16F27E, #FC9775, #5A69A6';
             var acolor = arrcolor.split(',');
             for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
                 var obj = {};
                 obj.color = acolor[i];
                 obj.value = dataValues[i].Accountvalues;
                 obj.label = dataValues[i].Accounts;
                 arr.push(obj);

             }
             // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options
             var ctx = $("#myChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
             var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(arr);
         }
    </script>
---here is the CS File
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static List<Chatdata> GetDataonload()
        {
            List<Chatdata> dataList = new List<Chatdata>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=203.115.195.52;Initial Catalog=mcom_ad_engine;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=appl;Password=mcom007;"))
            {
                string publisherid = "2000105";
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(publisherid))
                {
                    //string StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-180).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    string StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-60).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    string EndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Sp_publisher_Totalunpaied_pichart", con);
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 50;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@publisherid", publisherid);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@istartdate", StartDate);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ienddate", EndDate);
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    con.Close();
                    foreach (DataRow dtrow in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        if (dtrow[0].ToString() != "Total Earned")
                        {
                            Chatdata details = new Chatdata();

                            details.Accounts = dtrow[0].ToString();
                            // details.spent = Convert.ToInt64(dtrow[2].ToString());
                            if (dtrow[1].ToString().StartsWith("-"))
                            {
                                string bal = dtrow[1].ToString();
                                bal = bal.Substring(1, bal.Length - 1);
                                details.Accountvalues = Convert.ToInt64(bal);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                details.Accountvalues = Convert.ToInt64(dtrow[1].ToString());
                            }

                            dataList.Add(details);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //navigate to Login Page
                }
                return dataList;
            }
        }
```

Comment: in this line var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(arr);  getting error like Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).Pie is not a function...